# Cross compile kernel module for Zynq

Tags: linux, build, kernel, arm, cross-compiling

I have Zynq target running on

```
3.2.35-rt52 #1 SMP PREEMPT RT Wed Jun 12 09:57:26 CDT 2013 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I need to add Ethernet bonding driver kernel module  , but got errors can you help me on this ?

My steps

1) ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-i386

2)`sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi`

3) `https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x/linux-3.2.35.tar.gz`

4)`make distclean`

5)`make ARCH=arm defconfig`

6)`ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- make all`

After compile i have uploaded `bonding.ko` file to my target and try to load using `insmod`

I have got error

`insmod: can't insert '/lib/modules/3.2.35-rt52/kernel/drivers/net/bonding/bonding.ko': invalid module format

```
no symbol version for module_layout
```

`
This problem can come from SMP? 
My target have 2 cores and enabled SMP but in my module info i cant se SMP

Can you help me build loadable module for my Zynq target

thanks in advance

Comment: did you solve the problem?? i have same problem and if you can please give me the sloution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has nothing to do with SMP.

You'll need to use matching kernel version, kernel configuration, and toolchain for your module as for the kernel you are running on the Zynq.

If you are starting from one of the Targeted Reference Designs, it will include instructions for how to build the kernel. Unless they distribute kernel headers, you will have to build the kernel so that you can build a module that will insmod successfully.